# Почему округление до сотых при помощи ROUND() в MySQL округляет вниз?

Tags: mysql, sql

Выполняю запрос к БД MySQL, чтобы получить проценты за платеж:

```
select cp.id,
    cp.percent,
    round(cp.percent, 2)
from payment cp
where cp.id = 4118098
    and month(cp.payment_date) = 9
```

Выдаёт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: почему округление до сотых округляет вниз, хотя на конце цифра 5?

При этом запрос `select round(75.725, 2)` округляет всё корректно - до 75.73.
Тип столбца `percent` в таблице как `double`.

Comment: *For approximate-value numbers, the result depends on the C library. On many systems, this means that ROUND() uses the “round to nearest even” rule: A value with a fractional part exactly halfway between two integers is rounded to the nearest even integer.* [Мануал](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round).

Comment: Попробуйте поставить 3-ий параметр, чтобы было вот так: `round(cp.percent, 2, 0)`

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev В MySQL функция ROUND() не имеет третьего параметра.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `ROUND(percent, 2)` на `CAST(percent, DECIMAL(5,2))`.

Comment: @Akina да, походу, он в БД записан как 75.7249999999, что влияет на `round`, `cast` помогает привести в нормальный вид. оформите как ответ для других участников?

Comment: @Alex Не вопрос, сделано...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> почему округление до сотых округляет вниз, хотя на конце цифра 5?
>
> Тип столбца percent в таблице как double.

Тип DOUBLE относится к т.н. "неточным" типам данных - т.е. используемое для его хранения двоичное представление не в точности равно введённому, а лишь максимально близко к нему. Как итог - печально известные 0,1000000001 или 0,0999999999 вместо введённого изначально 0,1. И false при сравнении такого значения с непосредственно заданным в виде литерала значением 0,1.

В соответствии с [документацией](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) для таких типов данных

> For approximate-value numbers, the result depends on the C library. On
>   many systems, this means that ROUND() uses the “round to nearest even”
>   rule: A value with a fractional part exactly halfway between two
>   integers is rounded to the nearest even integer.

или, если по-русски, "результат округления зависит от используемой библиотеки функций, во многих случаях выполняется округление к ближайшему чётному" (т.н. "бухгалтерское" округление).

Для того, чтобы получить округление "половина - вверх", необходимо привести сначала имеющееся значение к "точному" числовому типу, т.е. желаемое округление можно было бы получить так:

```
SELECT ROUND(CAST(cp.percent AS DECIMAL(6,3)), 2)
```

Однако приведение типа само по себе требует округления (помним, что исходное значение-то у нас неточное!), а потому есть смысл сразу выполнять приведение к нужному конечному типу, т.е. с нужным количеством десятичных знаков. И окончательный вариант будет выглядеть как

```
SELECT CAST(cp.percent AS DECIMAL(5,2))
```

---

> При этом запрос select round(75.725, 2) округляет всё корректно - до 75.73.

В данном случае константа-литерал сразу создаётся с типом DECIMAL. Потому и округление работает, как указано в той же документации:

> For exact-value numbers, ROUND() uses the “round half away from zero”
>   or “round toward nearest” rule: A value with a fractional part of .5
>   or greater is rounded up to the next integer if positive or down to
>   the next integer if negative. (In other words, it is rounded away from
>   zero.) A value with a fractional part less than .5 is rounded down to
>   the next integer if positive or up to the next integer if negative.

или, если по-русски, "округление к ближайшему целому в направлении от нуля", т.е. положительные - вверх, а отрицательные - вниз.

---

PS. Обратите внимание - функции преобразования типа [CAST() и CONVERT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html) вообще не предусматривают приведения числа к неточному числовому типу.